# Displaying posts from owned facebook with the PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So I admittedly am quite new to the facebook Graph api, but what I want to do feels like it should be doable.

All I want to do is display posts from a facebook page that is owned by me on a website.

Now I should say that I have achieved this with the api and the php sdk already, but its all of the access token stuff that is perplexing me, I just want a permanent access token so that I don't have to renew it in anyway.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to ask a specific question on here - maybe you could show the code you already have that has achieved what you want, how you've tried to add the access token functionality and what is not working as you like.  See the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for tips.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extendingpagetokens

Comment: Thanks a lot for both getting back to me, I think I've managed to get a never(maybe?) expiring page access token now from the api, so thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone landed on this question and was looking for direction on this subject too

```
$client = array(
    "id" => {APP_ID},
    "secret" => {APP_SECRET},
    "token" => {ACCESS_TOKEN}, // Generated from the graph api explorer, with the 'manage_posts' extended permission ticked
    "page" => {PAGE_ID}
);

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($client['id'], $client['secret']);

$session = new FacebookSession($client['token']);

try
{
    $response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id='.$client['id'].'&client_secret='.$client['secret'].'&fb_exchange_token='.$client['token']))->execute();
    $results = $response->getGraphObject();
    $data = $results->asArray();

    $token = $data['access_token'];

    $response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/'.$client['page'].'?fields=access_token'))->execute();
    $results = $response->getGraphObject();
    $data = $results->asArray();

    echo "Access Token: ".$data['access_token']; // this is your never expiring access token
}
catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Obviously I do not recommend doing this in any form of production environment, but if you are in a local environment and just need the access token, feel free to use this to find out the access token.